# How can I apply the SSL verification disable process that I performed in Postman in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcZMt.png)

How can I apply the SSL verification disable process that I performed in Postman in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl):

> **The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc.** This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers.

So SSL verification is "disabled" in JMeter by default and by design, there is nothing you need/can do about it.

---

The funny thing is that there is no easy way to enable it, if you need to test SSL handshake or want JMeter to fail if the SSL connection is not secure - you will have to write the code for establishing the connection using [JSR223 Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score -1):

Update your jmeter.properties that is read when jmeter starts up, add the following:

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```